# Ограничения в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgsql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как возможно сделать сделать эти ограничения

- Диагнозы не могут противоречить друг другу.
- Постановка диагноза должна совпадать по времени и дате с приемом.
  Структуру БД прикрепил на рисунке
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запретить ввод и корректировку данных запросами и переместить логику в хранимые процедуры. Где и производить все необходимые проверки. Это если делать правильно.

Comment: А более простой способ существует?

Comment: Неужели тут простыми ограничениями типа EXCLUDE и CHECK не отделаться?

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста!!! HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал связи по другому и проблем бы не было. Введите в журнал приема диагноз ид если он один или в диагноз таблицу журнал приема ид если диагнозов несколько. Уберите дату из диагноза поскольку не будет смысла в случае существование связей. Поставьте ограничения на вторичные ключи и будет нормально.

После этих манипуляций журнал записи станет основной таблицей в базе